# RemoteApp on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access

So I have been trying to use RemoteApp on Ubuntu 16.04 from my Windows PC, but I don't know how to open the .rdp file on Ubuntu. I have read to use FreeRDP, but haven't found instructions that explain how to do it. Could someone here shed a little bit of light on how I might do this?

Answer (score -1):

The thing is you want to access your PC remotely? Well you can try [Team Viewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) though. I use this app frequently to remote Ubuntu and Mac from another PC.

It has various support to remote Linux, Windows, Mac. It even enable you to remote from Android.

Sorry, maybe I don't answer your question. It just I give you another option if you want to remote your PC :)

Comment: I don't want to use remote desktop, I want to use RemoteApp which launches the remote desktop and only shows that windows, not the whole desktop.

Comment: Team Viewer uses centeral servers, it runs a separate service on host along with the default RDP service.